# Ajax not submitting to URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I call the POST function on the same page it's being submitted on it echo's what I submitted but when I try and echo it on the page it's submitted to it doesn't appear.

Everything is the same as it appears except the "include" function that calls the full url.

**The Page:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('form#PTan').on('submit', function(e) {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/submittest.php',
success: function (o) {
console.log(o)
alert('MUST ALERT TO DETERMINE SUCCESS PAGE');
}
});
e.preventDefault();
});
});     
</script>

<form action='' id='PTan'  method='post'>
<select class='formstyle' id='PTan' name='PTan'>
  <option value='Beige'>Beige</option>
  <option value='Dark'>Dark</option>
  <option value='Light'>Light</option>
</select>
   <input type='submit' name='submit'  value='Submit' />
</form>

<?php
   $PTan = $_POST['PTan'];

   echo $PTan;

   include "/submittest.php";

?>
```

**Submittest.php**

```
<?php
$PTan = $_POST['PTan'];

echo $PTan;
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, your form and select both have the same `id` --- ID's are unique, unlike a class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you missed jquery library ? if yes add it to the `<head></head>`

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('form#PTan').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/submittest.php',
        data: $('#PTan').serialze(), //Add data attr to the ajax function 
        success: function (o) {
            console.log(o);
            alert('MUST ALERT TO DETERMINE SUCCESS PAGE');
        }
    });

});
```

});

```
<form action='' id='PTan'  method='post'>
<select class='formstyle' id='P' name='PTan'>
  <option value='Beige'>Beige</option>
  <option value='Dark'>Dark</option>
  <option value='Light'>Light</option>
</select>
   <input type='submit' name='submit'  value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: It's still doing the same thing for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Your server side code is trying to examine `$_POST['PTan']`, but you haven't sent that in the Ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: { 
      "PTan": "something" 
  },
  url: '/submittest.php',
```

Comment: What should I put in the "something" you should i call a var?